# Using "Matrix" package methods in a custom R package

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Following code is a function in a custom R package.

```r
#' @import Matrix
#' @export
asdf <- function(){
    u <- Matrix(0,5,5)
    rowSums(u)
}
```

When I load the package and execute it, I get the following output.

```r
> library(devtools); document(clean=TRUE); load_all()
Loading required package: roxygen2
Updating gm documentation
Loading gm
Loading required namespace: Matrix
Loading required package: Matrix
Writing gm.generate.Rd
Loading gm
> asdf
function(){
    u <- Matrix(0,5,5)
    rowSums(u)
}
<environment: namespace:gm>
>
> asdf()
Error in rowSums(u) (from tmp.R#5) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

So, even though the Matrix package is loaded, `rowSums` in the Matrix package is not getting dispatched even though Matrix package is imported in the `NAMESPACE`:

```r
export(asdf)
import(Matrix)
```

In the global environment, the Matrix package is indeed loaded, and `rowSums` function is available.

```r
> showMethods(rowSums)
Function: rowSums (package base)
x="ANY"
x="CsparseMatrix"
x="ddenseMatrix"
x="denseMatrix"
x="dgCMatrix"
x="dgeMatrix"
x="diagonalMatrix"
x="dsCMatrix"
    (inherited from: x="CsparseMatrix")
x="igCMatrix"
x="indMatrix"
x="lgCMatrix"
x="ngCMatrix"
x="RsparseMatrix"
x="TsparseMatrix"
```

However, if I define the same function in the global environment, everything works properly:

```r
> qwer <- function(){
    u <- Matrix(0,5,5)
    rowSums(u)
}

qwer <- function(){
+     u <- Matrix(0,5,5)
+     rowSums(u)
+ }
> qwer()
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

I am puzzled by this. What am I doing wrong?

================================================================

In `NAMESPACE` file:

```
Package: hola
Type: Package
Title: What the package does (short line)
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-01-03
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: Who to complain to <yourfault@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: What license is it under?
```

In `DESCRIPTION` file:

```r
export(asdf)
import(Matrix)
importFrom(Matrix,Matrix)
importFrom(Matrix,rowSums)
```

In `R/asdf.R` file:

```r
#' @import Matrix
#' @importFrom Matrix Matrix
#' @importFrom Matrix rowSums
#' @export
asdf <- function(){
    u <- Matrix(0,5,5)
    rowSums(u)
}
```

Comment: What does your NAMESPACE file look like?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am importing Matrix package. I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read [1.5.6 Namespaces with S4 classes and methods](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Namespaces-with-S4-classes-and-methods)

Add this to your NAMESPACE file:

```
import(Matrix)
```

or better:

```
importFrom(Matrix, rowSums)
```

Also, `Imports: Matrix` in DESCRIPTION file is needed.

Bare minimum package is as follows:

---

`DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Package: hola
Type: Package
Title: What the package does (short line)
    Version: 1.0
    Date: 2014-01-03
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: Who to complain to <yourfault@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: What license is it under?
Imports:
    Matrix
```

---

`NAMESPACE` file:

```r
export(asdf)
importFrom(Matrix,Matrix)
importFrom(Matrix,rowSums)
```

---

`R/asdf.R` file:

```r
#' @importFrom Matrix Matrix
#' @importFrom Matrix rowSums
#' @export
asdf <- function(){
    u <- Matrix(0,5,5)
    rowSums(u)
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks. I tried reading the section, but Perhaps I missed something. Also, I should have mentioned that I am indeed importing the Matrix package. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: what do you have in you description file. I test this in a new package  and it works fine for me.

Comment: I think the example (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#An-example) shows what might be happening, but the example does not say how to use custom function "c <- function(...) sum(...)" from "foo" package.

Comment: Package: gm
    Type: Package
    Title: What the package does (short line)
    Version: 1.0
    Date: 2013-10-28
    Author: NAME
    Maintainer: NAME <placeholder@email.com>
    Depends:
        Matrix
    Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    License: What license is it under?

Comment: I have tried making a minimal package but still no joy. I have updated the question to include NAMESPACE, DESCRIPTION and asdf.R files. I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: in you descrption file you should add Imports:Matrix or depends:Matrix

Comment: That worked. I didn't know both were necessary. I edited your answer to include a full example codes. Thank you, Agstudy.